# using table to store vectors,containing customized bitmap and editfields

Tags: java, vector, bitmap, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

hi i am newbie to blackberry.i will be having two buttons one for addition   of rows and other for deletion of rows.

```
|--------------------------------------------|
||----------------------------------||------||
||labelfield                        ||Bitmap||
||__________________________________||______||
|____________________________________________|
|--------------------------------------------|
|    Editfield                               |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

Above is customized view of datepicker,Where on click of bitmap datepicker    popups to choose date and that date value get binded to edit field,this is contained in one row and other row contains an edit field which allows to enter amount which shall be formatted as user enter's numerals.

Initially two default row will be present to choose date and enter amount.On click of add button these two rows shall be added.and these rows values will be retrieved whenever required.

similarly on click of deletion button these two rows will get deleted.If user has to add next  two rows the previous rows must be filled.

the code i have used for datepicker is given below

```
 VerticalFieldManager datevertfield = new VerticalFieldManager();
 String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
 String dateInString = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(new Date());

    LabelField lblcal1 = new LabelField("Date", DrawStyle.LEFT
            | Field.FIELD_LEFT) {

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0xffffff);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    datevertfield.add(lblcal1);
    HorizontalFieldManager datepickerHoriztalField = new       HorizontalFieldManager();
    HorizontalFieldManager dateHoriztalField = new HorizontalFieldManager()     
     {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth() - horiwidth, horiheight);
            setExtent(Display.getWidth() - horiwidth, horiheight);
        }
    };
    XYEdges xyEdge1 = new XYEdges(border, border, border, border);
    XYEdges xyEdgeColors1 = new XYEdges(0x2AACFF, 0x2AACFF, 0x2AACFF,
            0x2AACFF);
    Border aBorder1 = BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(xyEdge1,
            xyEdgeColors1, Border.STYLE_SOLID);

    dateHoriztalField.setBorder(aBorder1);
    datepickerHoriztalField.add(dateHoriztalField);
    BitmapField iconimg = new BitmapField(
            GPATools.ResizeTransparentBitmap(
                    Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Calender.png"),
                    imgwidth, imgheight, Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS,
                    Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT), Field.FOCUSABLE) {
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            try {
                DateTimePicker datePicker = DateTimePicker.createInstance();
                datePicker.doModal();

                Calendar cal = datePicker.getDateTime();
                datePicker.setMaximumDate(cal.getInstance());
                Date curtime = cal.getTime();

                DateFormat formattertime = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "MM/dd/yyyy");
                String currentTime = formattertime.format(curtime);
                txtpickdate.setText(currentTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return true;
        }
    };
        txtpickdate = new LabelField("Enter Date", DrawStyle.LEFT
            | Field.FIELD_LEFT) {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    dateHoriztalField.add(txtpickdate);
    datepickerHoriztalField.add(iconimg);
    datevertfield.add(datepickerHoriztalField);
    add(datevertfield);
```

This is code used for date picker row like this i want to add datepiker row and next edit field row on click of butn .and this could be deleted on click of delete btn.
In this i need to know how to add and delete these rows and how to know whether user has entered previous Date and edit field row to do validation.

Could anyone give me idea on how to start with this.Code example will be appreciated.

Comment: You should ask a question about a specific issue, this is too broad to even hope for an answer. In this case the best option would be to make a custom field that manages its state. On your screen you'll then have relatively clean code as you will simply add the field x number of times, and delete via a callback

Comment: @Kevin Plz look at new added code.give me idea on how to do this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question or not, but from what I understand you are looking for:

- A label & Button to select date
- EditField restricted to numerical text
- Button to create a field from a date and number
- Created Fields can be deleted

I created a smallish example for doing this. I did not include the number restriction on the text field, but the rest should be a decent base to start from. I would recommend not using a `BitmapField` as a button because it won't be good for ux. You'll likely want a field with images for each state (none, focused, pressed)

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{   
    private Calendar calendar;
    private LabelField labelField;
    private BitmapField bitmapField;
    private EditField editField;
    private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    public MyScreen()
    {
        super(NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);

        // ----- TODO ------
        // Too lazy to include a bmp, so I generated one. You should replace this with your icon
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(50, 50);
        Graphics g = Graphics.create(bmp);
        g.setColor(0xEFEFEF);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        // ------------------

        bitmapField = new BitmapField(bmp, FOCUSABLE)
        {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
            {
                if (calendar == null)
                {
                    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                }

                DateTimePicker datePicker = DateTimePicker.createInstance(calendar);
                datePicker.doModal();

                calendar = datePicker.getDateTime();
                if (calendar == null)
                {
                    labelField.setText("null"); // Your error message here
                }
                else
                {
                    labelField.setText(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        labelField = new LabelField(null, USE_ALL_WIDTH) // Tell labelField to use as much width as possible
        {
            protected void layout(int width, int height)
            {
                // Layout the label as though less space is available (to fit the bitmap button in)
                super.layout(width - bitmapField.getBitmapWidth(), height);
            }
        };

        HorizontalFieldManager manager = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        add(manager);
        manager.add(labelField);
        manager.add(bitmapField);

        editField = new EditField(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        add(editField);

        ButtonField addButton = new ButtonField("ADD")
        {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
            {
                String text = editField.getText();
                if ((calendar != null) && (text != null) && (text.length() > 0))
                {
                    add(new EntryField(calendar.getTime(), text));
                }
                else
                {
                    // TODO notify invalid data?
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        add(addButton);
    }

    public class EntryField extends HorizontalFieldManager
    {
        public EntryField(Date date, String text)
        {
            super(USE_ALL_WIDTH);

            // ----- TODO ------
            // Too lazy to include a bmp, so I generated one. You should replace this with your icon
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(50, 50);
            Graphics g = Graphics.create(bmp);
            g.setColor(0xFF0000);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            // ------------------

            final BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField(bmp, FOCUSABLE)
            {
                protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
                {
                    EntryField.this.getManager().delete(EntryField.this); // Remove this field from its parent
                    // Depending on what kind of interactions this field exposes, this will most likely need to make use of a callback instead.

                    return true;
                }
            };

            final LabelField labelField = new LabelField(formatter.format(date) + " - " + text, USE_ALL_WIDTH) // Tell labelField to use as much width as possible
            {
                protected void layout(int width, int height)
                {
                    // Layout the label as though less space is available (to fit the bitmap button in)
                    super.layout(width - bitmapField.getBitmapWidth(), height);
                }
            };

            add(labelField);
            add(bitmapField);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to add edit field and date picker field so user enters date by clicking on calender icon.But in your code i am getting these fields which is already entered previous in first before clciking add button.I need a Delete Button Next to Add Butn  so that on clcik of delete butn last entered Edit field and datepicker field should get deleted.Main thing is that what ever user enter's for date field and label field those datas have to be sent to service while calling service so how could i store these values and retrieve these values by using vectors.